# Blender not recognizing 1060 gpu, even with latest drivers

Tags: rendering, gpu

I am using Blender 2.78a with a gtx 1060 with latest drivers installed on Windows, and for a few days I haven't been able to render using the gpu, as Blender doesn't seem to recognize it
[image: No cuda device]

I've already tried reinstalling the drivers, but it doesn't seem to solve the problem, and the card works with every other software

Comment: Was the GPU working before? If so, it is possible that some auto-update on the OS has changed your configuration. Try do downgrade the driver of the GPU to an earlier one.

Comment: Also try using the latest version of Blender, 2.78c, or a daily build from builder.blender.org.